# DNA Second cousin

Tags: dna

My husband recently discovered that he is 52% European Jewish through an Ancestry test. He matched with a female second cousin that is 100% European Jewish. Is there a way to know which side (mother or father) of her family he’s related on?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way that I know of is to find a third person related to both of them, and see which side of the family that they are on.  Given the closeness of the relationship (2nd cousin), finding a third person shouldn't be hard.

If your husband's parents (either/both) are still alive, have them take an Ancestry test.

Comment: Thanks! His mother is deceased (she would’ve been 92 if she were living). There’s a possibility that his biological father could be alive, but we have no idea who his biological father is/was.

Comment: How about cousins, then? Does he have any cousins?

Comment: We found his cousins through DNA testing. The female cousin is a 2nd cousin on his father’s side. We can easily make the distinction because his father is 100 % Jewish and his mother was African American. There are other cousin matches, for example a 3rd cousin who is also 100% Jewish and is also a shared match with the female 2nd cousin. However, the surnames in the (2nd cousin and 3rd cousin’s) trees are different. There are tons of newspaper articles for the 2nd cousins father and mother. I just don’t understand how to figure out which side he’s related to.